# Relative positioning HTML elements over a transformed image element

Tags: html, css, graphics, webkit-transform

Let's say I have an image element which is basically a 2D map and that I applied the following CSS transformation (using jQuery) on it:

```
$('#img').parent().css("perspective","696px");
$('#img').css("transform","rotateX(59deg) rotateY(2deg) rotateZ(-41deg)");
```

I applied this transformation to get a "fake perspective" effect over a 2D image, now I have a set number of coordinates mapped into this image which points to X,Y position in it

What I wanted to know is if there's any technique or way for me to calculate the "new" X,Y position of each point given this transformation

Just to clarify, I have no knowledge of computer graphics theories, I was just trying to develop this proof of concept and was trying to find the best way to give an HTML image this perspective effect and at the same time keep the image interactive letting the user click on each point mapped to that image

---

Update 1

I found a method called "getBoundingClientRect" that returns the rectangle coordinates after its transformation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) and I guess I need to apply some kind of matrix transformation given my original point using this new rectangle right?
sorry I really don't understand computer graphics theories and just wanted to try this way to see it would work